# Eslint & SAPUI5: How to remove "sap/$ not defined"?

Tags: sapui5, eslint

I am using Eslint in Visual Code for my SAPUI5 project. Whenever I am defining a controller using

```
 sap.ui.define([...
```

Eslint throws the error `sap not defined.`. The same holds for $/jQuery. Is there a way how to solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can whitelist global variables in the eslint configuration: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring (see "Specifying Globals").

> To configure global variables inside of a configuration file, use the
>   globals key and indicate the global variables you want to use. Set
>   each global variable name equal to true to allow the variable to be
>   overwritten or false to disallow overwriting. For example:

```
{
    "globals": {
        "var1": true,
        "var2": false
    }
}
```

Usually you have some kind of `.eslintrc.js` file where you can include this.

Here is an example: https://github.com/pulseshift/openui5-gulp-starter-kit/blob/master/.eslintrc.js